# Angular Route definition for get query parameter

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm looking for the route definition which should match for any request like `?p=%20some%random%20query`. My current definition for the routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
{ path: 'blog/:title', component: BlogComponent },
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },];
```

My idea was to get the query param `p` with `{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent }` and

```
 ngOnInit() {
     let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('p');
 }
```

. But it seems angular only supports queries with the structure /:a/:b. For example the query http://localhost:4200?p=yoyoyo will be transformed to http://localhost:4200/yoyoyo. Same result for `http://localhost:4200/?p=/blog/Add%20Token` which will be transformed into `http://localhost:4200/blog/Add%20Token`. Because of this I'm unable to retriev the value of the query param `p`. How can I make a route which will work for `p=%` and how can I retriev the value of `p`?

Can this be achieved by intercepting the route process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following set up worked.

First, I had to remove the route `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },`.

Then I created the following route (and PageNotFound component) for handling the p parameter `{ path: ':p', component: PageNotFoundComponent },`.

In the `PageNotFoundComponent` I was able to retrieve the `p` parameter with its value. Depending on its value I decide the next route.

```
ngOnInit() {
 let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('p');
 if (id == null) {
  this.Link = "/home";
 }
 else {
  this.Link = "/" + this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('p');
 }
 this.router.navigate([this.Link]);
}
```

If someone navigates to the page `http://localhost:4200/?p=/blog/Add%20Token` the `p` route will be hit and the request is forwarded to the PageNotFound component. In the component it self, I decide whats happening next. The value of the variable `id` would be `blog/Add%20Token`.

[EDIT] I use this solution successfully for handling githubpage redirects in combination with this [404.html](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) page and the angular app.

Answer (score 0):

for me the only place where this would actually work is the home route itself.   the '' and '**' are just 'redirects to the homecomponent

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent },
{ path: 'blog/:title', component: BlogComponent },
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },];
```

in homecomponent you need to subscribe to get the changes

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(value => console.log(value) )

}
```

Comment: Thats what I'm currently doing. Do you have a solution for the auto transformation of `http://localhost:4200/?p=/blog/Add%20Token` to `http://localhost:4200/blog/Add%20Token` ?

Comment: I've tested it here, for me it works.  I've tried `http://localhost:4200/nonexisting?p=value` and it forwards to 'home' with the queryparams available.  I just double checked for the same route without anything `http://localhost:4200/?p=value` works as well

Comment: really make sure you use subscribe method , the  let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('p'); form does not work.   In short: I do not have this auto transform issue.

Comment: I made changes to the answer to have exactly a 1:1 copy of my config for the routes that matter.  can you please try with that.

Comment: What I meant by transforming is that the url gets written from `http://localhost:4200/?p=value` to http://localhost:4200/home. The same applies for `http://localhost:4200/blog/Add%20Token` which forwards to `http://localhost:4200/blog/Add%20Token` and removes the p param. For me the queryParams callback prints only [object] which is an empty prototyp with no more information.

Comment: Yes, The problem is clear, but for some reason I cannot reproduce it here.  Sorry, for having stated obvious and duplicate things but I tried several variants and they all work